# How to pass ajax value to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass values to controller using Ajax. However I'm not able to successfully achieve this. The same approach however works fine in other apps were I have not used Codeigniter.

fblogin.js

```
function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

  //removed to shorten the code

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/auth/login",
    data: {fbname: name, 
           fbid: id, 
           fbemail: email, 
           fbgender: gender,               
           fbimageURL: imageURL},
    success: function(data){
    /*This will be changed using a Ajax function on a later date so that the data is updated without page refresh*/ 
    console.log("Data sent to server");
    confirm("You have successfully logged in with FB");
    window.location.reload();
    }
});

});
}
```

Controller (Auth.php)

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();       
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}

public function login() { 

    $this->load->view('templates/pop_up_header.php');
    $this->load->view('app/');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
}
```

The error that I get over here is

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How can I fix this? I'm new to Codeigniter.

Comment: browse to http://localhost:8080/auth/login with the browser and check if you are getting error 500, if so, then the problem is not related to CI. My guess is that there is something wrong with your htaccess